# How to set date format to a range properly?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, date-formatting

When I set a Date format to cells, it doesn't change format to dates, it is still Plain text format.

When it is a date format you can see the calendar in a cell when double-clicking (like on the picture that I attached at the bottom).

How to set the date format to a range properly?

p.s. see another screenshot below with data validation from a named range.[image]

```
//dates range
var weekEndingsRange = ss.getRangeByName("StatisticsWeeks")

weekEndingsRange.setNumberFormat('mmm dd, yyy')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(did you try the proper way?) **set up Data Validation for valid date:**

[image: 0]

---

**and then use the internal/native formatting of Google Sheets:**

[image]

Comment: Hi! I have a named range in data validation for a cell. Please see the post updates with a screenshot. Your second screen is same as I have, that is ok.

Comment: as **Criteria** you need to select **Date**

Comment: I got your point! Thanks! I will make a piece of code enforcing data validation to cells.